# RegistryTools in C#

Tags: c#, com

i'm trying to do this:

```
#region COM Registration Methods
/// <summary>
/// Performs COM and GAC registration services
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type"></param>
[ComRegisterFunction]
public static void RegisterServer(Type type)
{
    // Create a new registry tools object
    RegistryTools registry = new RegistryTools()
    {
        Hive = PluginHive
    };
```

in my C# project in VS2010 and it give me this error

"Error  1   The type or namespace name 'RegistryTools' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I look for the references, but i don't find anything.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Nver heard of RegistryTool class. Notice you've tagged COM as well. Is it 3rd Party?

Comment: I need to get to classes, making me unable to help much. [This looks to be the source of the code](http://books.google.com/books?id=1RLMPcdq7CkC), though, on page 278.

Comment: You *really* need to know what you're doing when you write your own [ComRegisterFunction].  No special classes are needed, RegistryKey will work fine.  Getting it wrong however produces very hard to diagnose runtime errors.  It doesn't sound you know what you are doing, find help in your team or from a contractor.

Comment: i'm learning how to work with this...

Comment: What does registry tools do that you need it ? you know you can access the registry though the framework

Comment: i need it to write a new entry on the windows regist:

'registry.WriteValue(
                key,
                setting.Key,
                setting.Value,
                RegistryValueKind.String
                );'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already figured out how to solve the problem. I use this insted:

`RegistryKey clsidkey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(key);`